# Error when trying to copy with windows command prompt

Tags: javascript, command

I am running a script from package.json

```
`copy -r ./dist/myapp/* ./public && rd ./public/index.html`
```

It fails with the following error:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
npm : npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
At line:1 char:1
```

I am not sure of what I am doing run because the files do exist.
I am wondering if the command is wrote in windows as I came from linux system.

Comment: Here is the correct command on linux ```cp -r ./dist/myapp/* ./public && rm ./public/index.html```

Comment: I would highly recommend to use https://github.com/sindresorhus/cpy-cli NPM module for copying files. I believe it should be working on all OS and also works with non-existent directories which is (usually) very important to be aware off.